# How to convert MySQL script to plain SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way/tool to convert a MySQL script to plain SQL? I design my databases on MySQL with their tools but I'm trying to use Flyway to handle migrations. I would like to have the script on plain SQL so it applies to any Data base.

I know I can translate my scripts to plain SQL, I'm looking for a way to automate this in order to avoid redoing this each time the database model has to change for some reason.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

[phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) has a format option to try to output an export in DB2, MSSQL, Oracle, Traditional.

[image]

Comment: This is a way indeed. Hard to use from Java or such, but I did't specify it on the question.

Comment: @javydreamercsw Sorry I couldn't be of more assistance.